# Viewport units, keeping aspect ratio?

Tags: css, viewport, viewport-units

So I've just discovered viewport units, and I really want to use them.

First challenge: My element has a "base size" of 760x670 pixels. I want to use viewport units to scale it up so that either the height is `100vh`, or the width is `100vw`, whichever is smaller.

Unfortnately, although I can use `100vmin` to get the smaller of the two, I can only apply it to the width or the height, not both.

Currently I'm using:

```
#root {
    width: 760px;
    height: 670px;
    width: 100vw;
    height: calc(670vw/760);
}
```

This scales the width to fit the screen, resulting in vertical scrolling. This isn't too bad, but I'd prefer it if I could actually have it fit the viewport.

Comment: I'm testing in Chrome. It seems that `vw` units cannot be used inside `calc`. I tried stuff like `height: -webkit-calc(100vw/3)`. The only other browsers which support both `calc` and viewport units are IE10 and Safari 6, neither of which can be installed on my platform (Windows 7).

Comment: Btw, this should be possible with media queries, as you can branch code based on aspect ratio, e.g. `@media all and (min-aspect-ratio: 760/670) { ... }`.

Comment: It's a [WebKit bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=94158). So forget about Chrome/Safari. Firefox/Opera don't even implement viewport units. It seems that IE10 is the only browser that understands your code. `:)`

Comment: @ŠimeVidas You could make a good answer of those two comments.

Comment: @PavloMykhalov I've made it work in IE10. Answer is below. `:-)`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've made it work in IE10:

```
#elem {
    width: 100vw;
    height: calc((9/16)*100vw);
}

@media (min-aspect-ratio:16/9) {
    #elem {
        height: 100vh;
        width: calc((16/9)*100vh);
    }
}
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/C2ZGR/show/ (open in IE10 (preview version available for Windows 7); then re-size window, so that either the width, or height is very small)

I've used an element with the aspect ratio of 16:9, but the code can work for any aspect-ratio - just replace `16/9`, and `9/16` with your desired aspect ratio.

Btw, IE10 is the only browser in which this demo will work. Firefox/Opera don't implement viewport units yet, and the WebKit browsers currently have a bug where viewport units cannot be used inside `calc()`.