# CSS / JS fallback or alternative for calc with vw units

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, calc

I'm trying to figure out an alternative way to implement calc using vw units, as this isn't supported yet in Safari/mobSafari (probably IE too when I get to that). I've set up a [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/La7jmo62/) to show a simple example of how it differs for Safari. I've had a bash (unsuccessfully) with JS but with no success. Any pointers in the right direction appreciated - if there's a possible alternative via CSS that would be perfect.

It's basically recreating `left: calc(-50vw + 50%)` in a cross-browser supported way.

Comment: Safari supports `vw` units. What problem are you having?

Comment: It doesn't with calc unfortunately - if you inspect the element in the fiddle, you'll see the rule with calc is disabled in safari

Comment: Why do you even need `calc()` here? If you want that image to be 100% the width of the viewport, just make it `100vw` and `left: 0`.

Comment: The div is relatively positioned and needs to break out of the parent container to span full width. The image has a max width of 100% and scales with the viewport.

Comment: you should use something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21224411/css-calc-viewport-units-workaround

Comment: I'd make it `position: absolute` before I'd rely on `calc()`.