# line-height calc vh unit

Tags: css, viewport-units, css-calc

I have little bit complicated problem. I need to set `line-height` by difference of `vh` unit and `px` by `calc` in CSS. My idea is to set it by this code

```
line-height: calc(100vh - 100px);
```

It sounds easy but does not work. Why calc with these units does not works is described in [CSS Calc Viewport Units Workaround?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21224411/css-calc-viewport-units-workaround) where is this solved for `height` property by hacking margin and padding but it cannot be used for line-height property.

I see that problem is solved in Chrome, IE and Edge but I need to do this on Firefox too. In Firefox it show in developer tools

> Invalid property value.

Any idea? (JavaScript isn't solution for me)

Comment: Can you please make a [mcve] of how it is working in Chrome, IE, and Edge please?