# Is it possible to calc() aspect ratio of a device using just viewport units?

Tags: css, calc, viewport-units

Here is what I want to do:

```
font-size: calc(1em * 100vh/100vw) // Good intentions, bad results.
```

Or is there any other way or another `property` or mechanism that returns the `aspect ratio` of a device within the css? No javascript please that would be sacrilege! :-)

I have seen some q&a's on stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14115449/viewport-units-keeping-aspect-ratio) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21224411/css-calc-viewport-units-workaround) and articles that sound like they deal with this problem but aren't close enough.